# How to log an application's entire stacktrace in .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, logging, stack-trace, call-graph

I've just started work on an existing [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) application with about 40 active projects. While familiarizing myself with the project, I find myself constantly stepping through the application just to learn the structure and logic flow. It would make this process so much easier if I could let the application run and log every method call and review the log afterwards. I know I can add `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine` statements, but adding those statements to most methods in 40 projects sounds like overkill. Are there any good alternatives to this approach?

[CLR Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler) introduced me to the appropriate keyword 'call graph' which led me to a duplicate question, *[How can I see a visualization of a dynamic call graph for a .NET program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348881/how-can-i-see-a-visualization-of-a-dynamic-call-graph-for-a-net-program)*.

Comment: Duplicate, as noted by OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348881/how-can-i-see-a-visualization-of-a-dynamic-call-graph-for-a-net-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CLR Profiler](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/clrprofiler/releases) can give you the stack traces you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out [RedGate ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).  The purpose of ANTS is performance profiling, but the profiler does give you a very detailed view of what the profiled application is doing, lets you slice and dice the callstack and also lets you jump over to Visual Studio.  It's a bit spendy, but well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use something like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) to add the logging automatically for all the methods.