# reverse query method chain on c# assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, metadata

I want to write some code( or if there is tool that can give thsi info ) that can return chian of methods executed( or called) - giving a starting point (  a fully qualified method name ) as input.

I am hoping this can be done via querying metadata on a dotnet assembly.

thanks for any pointers in advance!

**update #1:** http://sequenceviz.codeplex.com/ gives ability to generate forward chain of sequence diagram. I am looking into being able to reverse lookup the same info. Like given a method if we can generate reverse graph for all places from where it can be called.

Comment: Are you interested in which methods are actually called when the code is running (dynamic analysis) or the graph of *potential* calls (static analysis).  The former can only be done using a runtime profiler tool, the latter can be determined by investigating the source code or assembly IL without actually running the code/program.

Comment: For the latter, tools like R# can do this from inside Visual Studio. Reflector.NET can do it on an assembly. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in latter part - i.e graph of potential calls( statci analysis). http://sequenceviz.codeplex.com/ looks good. I will look into this if this gives static analysis.

Comment: I checked SequenceWix it gives me forward chaining. from a method.
Is there a way to also check the same backwords ( i.e reverse lookup the chain from a method ) ?

Answer (score 1):

There was similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348881/how-can-i-see-a-visualization-of-a-dynamic-call-graph-for-a-net-program)

Which suggests several option like [.Net Reflector](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/), [SequenceWiz](http://sequenceviz.codeplex.com/), [nProf](http://code.google.com/p/nprof/). One of these might work for you.

Comment: I checked SequenceWix it gives me forward chaining. from a method.
Is there a way to also check the same backwords ( i.e reverse lookup the chain from a method ) ?

Answer (score 0):

use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class to get this info. StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build configurations.